# Roslyn - why all the type wrapping? Eg Document -> DocumentState -> DocumentInfo -> DocumentAttributes

Tags: c#, roslyn

Roslyn seems to store underlying information for its main types - Solutions, Projects, Documents and such - spread accross various classes that often contain or expose the same properties. I don't quite understand why, conceptually.

Let's take Document, for example. It exposes a bunch of properties (Id, Filepath, Name and so, inherited via TextDocument) which just return corresponding properties from a (Text)DocumentState instance.
This, in turn, exposes the same properties, which it just returns from an underlying DocumentInfo instance. And the DocumentInfo in turn just returns the properties from its underlying DocumentAttributes. So basically, you have

Document.Name -> TextDocumentState.Name -> DocumentInfo.Name -> DocumentAttributes.Name

Most other objects are constructed somarwhat similar, i.e. Project -> ProjectState -> ProjectInfo -> ProjectAttributes etc.

But .. why all that wrapping? What's the conceptual idea/benefit behind this?

I would understand a split into one easily serializable type (e.g. DocumentAttributes), and then one boxed type that would also contain runtime/non-serializable information such as a reference to the Workspace and so on. But that would leave me with two types (say, DocumentAttributes and Document) - why do we need further types such as the -State and -Info ones?

Thanks

Comment: I'd avoid the word boxing here. Boxing is a specific term of art within [.net/C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) and this isn't it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, fair enough - admittedly, couldn't really think of any better term .. will gladly edit if there's any better/concise way to phrase this?

Comment: Wrapper/Wrapping perhaps?